# problem in data load using nupy genfromtxt, python

Tags: python, genfromtxt

My text file (`test.out`) contains data arrangement are in three rows but the number of columns are different in each row. That is like shown below

```
2013  531 1155 24.0 L  19.219  76.766  0.2  JOY  3 0.0 0.4LJOY                1
CBN  SZ IPg      1155 26.58                              87    0.0110 15.1 134
CBN  SN ESg      1155 28.38                              87   -0.0210 15.1 134
```

It showing error while loading the data using import
numpy as np

```
d1=np.genfromtxt('test.out', dtype=str)
```

it shows error message:
raise ValueError(errmsg)

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 9 columns instead of 13)
    Line #3 (got 9 columns instead of 13)
```

How it can be loaded using numpy `genfromtxt`. If anybody can help it will be great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe read it as normal text file using standard `open()`, `read()`, `close()` and parse it on your own.

Comment: `numpy array` (and `pandas FataFrame`) are for tables which have the same number of data in every row (columns). How did you expect to keep this data in numpy array?

Comment: Thanks for response, Dear Furas. After removing the field space by  ',' of test.out file using shell"s script. I find the below commands is useful for the range of columns    np.genfromtxt(a,  dtype=str, delimiter=',', usecols=np.arange(0,8))                      Thank you